# XML serialized from classes created with xsd is not correct

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have an XML file (it's a SOAP request to an SAP ME Service).
The file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:me="http://sap.com/xi/ME">
  <soapenv:Header />
  <soapenv:Body>
    <me:ShopOrderByBasicDataQuery_sync>
      <me:ShopOrderByBasicDataQuery>
        <me:ShopOrder>BOXBUILD_LASER_TEST</me:ShopOrder>
        <me:SiteRef>
          <me:Site>TEST1</me:Site>
        </me:SiteRef>
      </me:ShopOrderByBasicDataQuery>
    </me:ShopOrderByBasicDataQuery_sync>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Using Paste Special I used Paste XML as Classes and got a number of classes.
I the created a new Envelope object

```
Envelope shoporder = new Envelope();
EnvelopeBody shoporderBody = new EnvelopeBody();
ShopOrderByBasicDataQuery_sync shoporderSync = new       ShopOrderByBasicDataQuery_sync();
ShopOrderByBasicDataQuery_syncShopOrderByBasicDataQuery shoporderDataQuery = new ShopOrderByBasicDataQuery_syncShopOrderByBasicDataQuery();

shoporderSync.ShopOrderByBasicDataQuery = shoporderDataQuery;
shoporderDataQuery.ShopOrder = "BOXBUILD_LASER_TEST";
shoporderDataQuery.SiteRef = new ShopOrderByBasicDataQuery_syncShopOrderByBasicDataQuerySiteRef();
shoporderDataQuery.SiteRef.Site = "TEST1";
shoporderSync.ShopOrderByBasicDataQuery = shoporderDataQuery;
shoporderBody.ShopOrderByBasicDataQuery_sync = shoporderSync;
shoporder.Body = shoporderBody;

string tmp = (string)SoapHelper.SerializeToXmlString(shoporder);
```

The string **tmp** contains this (after a bit of formatting)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <Body>
    <ShopOrderByBasicDataQuery_sync xmlns="http://sap.com/xi/ME">
      <ShopOrderByBasicDataQuery>
        <ShopOrder>BOXBUILD_LASER_TEST</ShopOrder>
        <SiteRef>
          <Site>TEST1</Site>
        </SiteRef>
      </ShopOrderByBasicDataQuery>
    </ShopOrderByBasicDataQuery_sync>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Which is not a correct file! What have I done wrong?

Comment: You are missing the prefixes 'me' and 'soapenv' which are the namespaces.

Comment: Ok, but how do I add these? I have just used the autocreated classes

Comment: Your XML is semantically exactly the same, and any processor should have no issue reading either one. Do you actually a problem?

Comment: @CharlesMager I don't know! I don't have access to the Web Services at the moment. But I will take your word on it being the same! Thanks

Comment: If you really want to add the same prefixes, you'll probably need to change something within `SerializeToXmlString`.